# Adding from textbox in form to datagridview in another form C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I Have form1 with 4 textboxes and 1 button, and I have form2 which contains dataGridView that filled by 4 columns from the dataset, I want to add new row to the datagridview from the other form.

but it give me this error:

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
```

This is my code on the Button Click.

```
Main frm = new Main();
frm.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = textBox1.Text;
frm.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = textBox2.Text;
frm.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = textBox4.Text;
frm.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
frm.dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
this.Hide();
frm.Show();
```

Comment: I cannot see form1 anywhere?

Comment: `private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Main frm = new Main();
            frm.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = textBox1.Text;
            frm.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = textBox2.Text;
            frm.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = textBox4.Text;
            frm.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
            this.Hide();
            frm.Show();
        }`

Comment: Move the line `frm.dataGridView1.Rows.Add();` right after the first line

Comment: ok I remove it but nothing happened

Comment: Either you have no rows or none or less than 4 columns. How do you __think__ the columns get created??